# JSP page not rendering properly when served from WAR

Tags: tomcat

I have a web project on Eclipse using Tomcat.  My web.xml declares a welcome file

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/testPage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Simple stuff,  when I run the server locally through eclipse and I browse to it through my browser it shows me my testPage.jsp and the buttons,  javascript works fine.
Now .  when I export the same app unchanged to a WAR and then deploy this on a seperate server and browse to this through the same browser the testPage.jsp displays as a plain text file,  ie it is not rendered properly, see below  I just see plain HTML text. Why does my browser not render the buttons correctly if the page is served from a WAR running on a standalone tomcat but works fine when served from Tomcat running within my Eclipse?

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/testPage.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.json-2.3.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                <tr>
                    <td><textarea id="annotationLookupInput"  style="margin-left:5px;width:300px;height:80px;" ></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="annotationLookup()" value="Lookup Annotation ID">
                    </td>
                    <td><textarea id="annotationLookupResult" style="margin-left:5px;width:300px;height:80px;" ></textarea></td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
                <tr>
                    <td><textarea id="annotationSaveIDInput"  style="margin-left:5px;width:80px;height:40px;" ></textarea>
                    <td><textarea id="annotationSaveValueInput"  style="margin-left:5px;width:100px;height:40px;" ></textarea>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="annotationSave()" value="Save/Update Annotation">
                    </td>
                    <td><textarea id="annotationSaveResult" style="margin-left:5px;width:300px;height:80px;" ></textarea></td>
                </tr>            
            </table>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly the JSPs should be placed directly inside the project folder and not inside `WEB-INF`.

You can try that and change the web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>testPage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```